# Immutable Transactions in hyperledger fabric

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Hi I have a query regarding **hyperledger fabric transactions**. So In fabcar example we created a car object in chain-code and manipulated it by changing its owner etc. My question is where are transactions in all this? and whats immutable? Can we get a transaction history from chain-code? or do we have to implement that login ourselves in the code to record and save data changes or operations in chaincode with dates?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you add new records or update an existing records, those will be consider as transactions with fabcar chaincode. You can find all those transactions by query the ledger.
2. Records and Transaction histories are immutable. For example, the current owner of Car1 is Syed. This records is immutable and no one can change this ownership illegally. Previously Syed bought this car from Zain. So the ownership is changed from Zain to Syed. All of those records are kept immutable.
3. Yes we can get all the previously history of a key by querying the ledger. You have to call "stub.GetHistoryForKey". You can find the answer in ["marbles_chaincode.js"](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/chaincode/marbles02/javascript/marbles_chaincode.js)
4. You don't need any login in public-key cryptography, for access control in chaincode, you can use attribute based access control or ABAC. Currently you can use "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/pkg/cid" packages for ABAC with go chaincode.

Comment: Thanks . But the main issue is in an web application you always need login and and registration. How are we suppose to do that with Access Control or certificates ?

Comment: Im not following you. I did red your articles. But im not clear with the architecture. If a User Access a blockchain system website made on fabric. He will need to Register and then Login. How will I achieve that behavior?

Comment: You can use fabric ca for registration(https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#registering-a-new-identity), all a user need is a private key and a valid certificate . Please study public key cryptography, digital certificate and how those works, so that you can understand everything properly.